# $\mu = m = \frac{q_1 +q_3}{2}$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with p.m.f./p.d.f. $f_X (x)$ that is symmetric about
$\mu (\in R),$ i.e., $f_X (x + \mu) = f_X (\mu − x)$, $\forall x \in (−\infty, \infty).$

If $q_1 , m$ and $q_3$ are respectively the lower quartile, the median and the upper
quartile of the distribution of $X$ then show that $\mu = m = \frac{q_1 +q_3}{2}$

How to prove.....

any Hints.

Answer (score 2):

Say, $q_1$ is the lower quartile, i.e. $P(X<q_1)=1/4$, that is, $\int_{-\infty}^{q_1} f_X(x)dx=1/4$. By symmetry about $\mu$, (by $\ t\mapsto 2\mu-t$), we also have $\int_{2\mu-q_1}^{\infty} f_X(x)dx=1/4$, that is, $P(X>2\mu-q_1)=1/4$, so $q_3=2\mu-q_1$.

Similarly, $P(X<\mu)=1/2$ by symmetry.

Comment: How to prove in case of Discrete random variable

Comment: How are the quartiles are defined then? E.g. what would $q_1$ and $q_3$ be at 'throwing a die'?

Comment: if $F_X(x)=\frac{1}{4}$ than $q_1=x$.if $F_X(x)=\frac{3}{4}$ than $q_3=x$

Comment: But the condition that $F_X(x)=\frac14$ might not define $x$ uniquely hence this does not answer @Berci's query.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add another interesting tidbit - if $E[X] < \infty$, then $$E[X] = \mu = m = \frac{q_1+q_3}{2}$$
$$\begin{align}E[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x) dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (2\mu - x)f_X(x)dx\\ &= 2\mu\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)dx \\&= 2\mu - E[X]\\
\implies E[X] &= \mu
 \end{align}$$